# Lie derivative "commutes" with pullback by time dependent diffeomorphisms

Tags: geometry, differential-geometry, manifolds, riemannian-geometry, smooth-manifolds

I've seen the following equality being used in a book on the Ricci flow I'm reading but I've been stuck on proving it:

$$\varphi_{t}^{*}\left(\mathcal{L}_{W(t)} g(t)\right)=\mathcal{L}_{\left[\left(\varphi_{t}^{-1}\right)_{*} W(t)\right]}\left(\varphi_{t}^{*} g(t)\right)$$

The context here is as follows: $(\mathcal{M}, g_0)$ is a Riemannian manifold on which  $W$ is a time dependent vector field, $\{g(t) \}_{t \in I}$ is a family of time-dependent metrics on $\mathcal{M}$, and the $1$-parameter family of diffeomorphisms $\varphi_{t}: \mathcal{M}^{n} \to \mathcal{M}^{n}$ satisfies the non autonomous ODE:

$$\begin{aligned}
\frac{\partial}{\partial t} \varphi_{t}(p) &=-W\left(\varphi_{t}(p), t\right) \\
\varphi_{0} &=\mathrm{Id}_{\mathcal{M}^{n}}
\end{aligned}$$

I don't have a lot of experience with Lie derivative computations and this is the last step I need to finally finish a proof that solutions to the Ricci-deTurck flow can be produced by solutions from the Ricci-Hamilton flow. I know that if $M$ and $N$ are smooth manifolds, $F: M \to N$ is a diffeomorphism and $X \in \mathcal{X}(M)$ it's true that $$F_{*}\left(\mathcal{L}_{V} X\right)=\mathcal{L}_{(F_{*} V)} (F_{*} X)$$
but I'm having a hard time adapting this to pullbacks where everything is time dependent. This has been troubling me for some time now, so I'll be grateful for any help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think that anything in the equation depends on time varying. Or rather the equation is a relation at fixed arbitrary times $t=t_0$. So you just obtain a diffeomorphism $\varphi_{t_0}$ and vector field $W(t_0)$ as for your example with $F$ and $V$. The equation should be interpreted as a family of fixed time equations.

Comment: That's true! My advisor had said the exact same thing you did to me a while ago but I forgot to put it here. Thanks!